# How to simply execute a comand on remote desktop

Tags: windows-xp, remote, remote-execution

I'm on Windows XP SP2 with no hack for concurrent sessions installed.
I want to simply execute a single command on this machine from another remote computer, and nothing else. I want to run it as either the user who's already logged in, or as a different user. I have administrator permission. 
The command will not be GUI-based, and I don't want to install a software on either host or client.

The client is running Linux (preferred), but I could also use Windows XP.

My major concern is that the user currently logged in should not be logged off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running a command on a remote machine can be done in multiple ways: [PowerShell remoting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands#windows-powershell-remoting), [`PsExec`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) from [Sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/), [remote desktop](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-allow-access) (`psexec` is probably the easiest for a one shot use), but these will all either create a new session or run as system.

I.e. they won't run as the logged in user on that remote machine.

If you don't really need to run as the logged in user see above. Otherwise group policy to set a login script might be the simplest approach.